# How to test the Knockout.js click binding with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jasmine

I'm having a problem with a jasmine test together with a knockout-template:

The html is similar to this:

```
<body>
<my-widget params="value: $data></my-widget>
</body>
```

the widget has a click-binding:

```
<div class="my-widget">
   <a id="#clickme" data-bind="click: doSomething">Click me</a>
</div>
```

the widget-javascript is like this:

```
ko.components.register('my-widget', {
    viewModel : function(params) {
        this.doSomething = function() {
              // doing something
        };
    },
    template: {
        require: 'text!../../templates/my-widget.html'
    }
});
```

All of this works perfectly in production, but in Jasmine/Jquery, triggering a click on $('#clickme') does not execute the doSomething.

The following is an excerpt from my jasmine test (It's been greatly simplified but should contain the essentials):

```
beforeEach(function (done) {
    require(['specHelpers', 'knockout'], 
        function (specHelpers, knockout) {
        specHelpers.loadFixtureIntoPage("page.html", "myPage"); // template and id to use
        expect($('#myPage')).toExist();
        done();
    });
});


it("WILL NOT TRIGGER MY CLICK", function (done) {
    ko.applyBindings(myPage.pageViewModel, $('#myPage'))[0]);

    setTimeout(function() { 
        $('#clickme').click();

        // doSomething is not called :(

        done();
    }, 300);
});
```

When console.logging the #clickme element I can see that it is present.

It seems that the click binding in the widget does not get applied properly. However, when I run the test in bdd and it's over and failed - I can manually click this element and doSomething does get called.

What am I doing wrong? As I said, running the actual application works perfectly. It just seems that jasmine cannot handle the click bindings properly - I don't have this problem with the regular click events that are set in the document.ready

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but couldn't.. https://jsfiddle.net/9qb1936v/ What did I miss?

Comment: The problem occurs when the entire thing is running in a jasmine spec, where the fixtures, i.e. the HTML that contains my knockout widget, are loaded dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be testing button clicks like that - you can be more certain if you just call the function doSomething() directly. Same way that you don't test any internals of JQuery yourself.

If you really really want to test events on a fixture, have you tried just

```
$("#clickme").trigger('click');
```

Also, double check that fixture is inserted into DOM in when you debug the test (say via browser)

Comment: I have tried that too - with the same result. And yes, the fixture is there. Console.log of the element I want to click shows this. The only thing that is NOT there is the click event that gets added through knockout. I can add others through jquery and they will work fine.

Comment: Regarding testing the function directly - we did that before, and it led to the tests not catching something that we accidentally broke during refactoring. That's the reason why we'd rather test the click itself

Comment: Ah I understand, I guess then it's value in that! :) I guess it's then up to how ko.applyBindings is set up